# Using input value in the JavaScript function name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create JavaScript function dynamically and want to use input value as function name.

I tried:

```
function calculate(){
var dur = document.getElementById('duration').value; //example value: 1
var sum = document.getElementById('sum_insured2').value; //example value: 1000  
`'show_d'+dur+'_sum'+sum();`
}
```

I want like this:

```
`show_d1_sum1000();`
```

I am not getting the output what I want.

Comment: what output are you getting ?

Comment: Can you show your HTML aswell please?

Comment: You want to declare a new function or to execute an already existing one?

Comment: try with window object like `window['show_d'+dur+'_sum'+sum]()`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dynamically call a function based on the value of variables in the manner you're attempting.

One workaround would be to put the function in an object and then use bracket notation to invoke the property, something like this:

```js
var funcs = {
  'show_d1_sum1000': function() { // 1 | 1000
    console.log('foo bar');
  }
}

var dur = document.getElementById('duration').value;
var sum = document.getElementById('sum_insured2').value;

funcs[`show_d${dur}_sum${sum}`]();
```

```html
<input type="text" value="1" id="duration" />
<input type="text" value="1000" id="sum_insured2" />
```

That being said, this is not a good pattern to follow. In your case I'd suggest executing a single statically defined function which handles the values of the inputs, whatever they may be.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this:

```
console.log('show_d' + dur.toString() + '_sum' + sum.toString());
```

In order to create a method dynamically by this name try this:

```
var name = 'show_d' + dur.toString() + '_sum' + sum.toString();

var f = new Function('name', 'return alert("hello world");');
```

and call the method using `f()`

If you have already a method in your window with the same name then try accessing it like this:

```
window[name](anyArguments);
```

Comment: how does this call the required function?

Comment: It is giving the correct name of function what I want but it is not calling it. How can I call it ?

Comment: Using the code of you it is giving as out put: show_d5_sum150000 but I want to call function like this show_d5_sum150000();  That is actually function name which is already defined on my page

Comment: Well, that doesn't call a method. It'll only take care of the naming part for the method.
I've updated the answer so that a method can be also called with dynamic name.

Comment: I have updated my question actually the code is already in a function name calculate()

Comment: @MubasharAhmad Updated the answer, please check

Comment: Thanks Deepak but I have resolved it by my self.

Comment: I have done it under php loop:

if(dur == '<?php echo $func_f['duration'];?>' && sum == <?php echo $func_f['sum_insured'];?>){
show_d<?php echo $func_f['duration'];?>_sum<?php echo $func_f['sum_insured'];?>(); 
}